# Mesclar dias em um calendário igual Google Calendar

Tags: php

Boa tarde Pessoal, tenho um calendário em php, que busca informações no banco de dados. E gostaria que os compromisso inseridos, fosse mesclado do inicio ao fim do mesmo. Igual ao google calendar. Vejam a imagem abaixo. Essa é minha atual visualização do calendario.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Reparem nos eventos "Teste evento 1" e "Teste de evento 3".
Gostaria que ficasse como na imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu código:

```
                    $data = date('d/m/y');
                    $data_explode = explode("/", $data);

                    $dia = $data_explode[0];
                    $mes = $data_explode[1];
                    $ano = $data_explode[2];
                    $calendario = "";

                    $v_mes = substr($mes, 0, 2);
                    $novo_mes = (int) $mes - 1;

                    $ultimo_dia_mes = date("t", mktime(0, 0, 0, $mes, 1, $ano));

                    $vetor_dias_semana = array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);

                    $vetor_mes = array("Janeiro", "Fevereiro", "Mar&ccedil;o", "Abril", "Maio", "Junho", "Julho", "Agosto", "Setembro", "Outubro", "Novembro", "Dezembro");

                    $calendario .="<div class='cabecalho_semana'>Domingo</div><div class='cabecalho_semana'>Segunda</div><div class='cabecalho_semana'>Terça</div><div class='cabecalho_semana'>Quarta</div><div div class='cabecalho_semana'>Quinta</div><div class='cabecalho_semana'>Sexta</div><div class='cabecalho_semana'>Sábado</div>";
                    $contador = 1;

                    $dia_semana_primeiro_dia = $dia_semana = date("w", mktime(0, 0, 0, $mes, 1, $ano));

                    $trava = "F";
                    $inicio = 1;

                    for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++) {
                        if ($dia_semana_primeiro_dia == $i || $trava == "T") {


                            $dados = connection::select("select * from agenda where (data_agenda <= '$ano-$mes-$inicio' AND termino_agenda >= '$ano-$mes-$inicio')");
                            //$dados = connection::select("select * from agenda as a inner join agendap as p on a.id_agenda = p.agenda_agendap where p.pessoa_agendap = $id_pessoa AND a.data_agenda = '$ano-$mes-$inicio' or a.termino_agenda = '$ano-$mes-$inicio'");
                            $reg = $dados->fetchObject();

                            if (!empty($reg)) {
                                $compromisso = '<small>';

                                $d = connection::select("select * from agenda where (data_agenda <= '$ano-$mes-$inicio' AND termino_agenda >= '$ano-$mes-$inicio')");

                                foreach ($d as $r) {
                                    $compromisso .= '#' . $r['id_agenda'] . ' - ' . $r['compromisso_agenda'] . '<br>';
                                }
                                $compromisso .= '</small>';

                                $calendario .="<div style='background-color:#fff;' class='cabecalho_dia' value='$ano-$mes-$inicio'><a href=" . URL . "agenda/data/$ano-$mes-$inicio>" . $inicio . "<br><font style='color:#fff;background-color:#166C25;'>" . $compromisso . "</font></a></div>";
                            }
                            else {
                                $calendario .="<div style='background-color:#fff;' class='cabecalho_dia' value='$ano-$mes-$inicio'><a href=" . URL . "agenda/data/$ano-$mes-$inicio>" . $inicio . "</a></div>";
                            }
                            $trava = "T";
                            $inicio++;
                        }
                        else {
                            $calendario .="<div style='background-color:#fff;' class='cabecalho_dia'>&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>";
                        }
                    }

                    $fim = "F";
                    $linha_semana = 1;
                    while ($fim == "F" || $linha_semana < 6) {

                        for ($f = 0; $f < 7; $f++) {

                            $linha_semana++;

                            if ($inicio <= $ultimo_dia_mes) {

                                $dados2 = connection::select("select * from agenda where (data_agenda <= '$ano-$mes-$inicio' AND termino_agenda >= '$ano-$mes-$inicio')");
                                //$dados2 = connection::select("select * from agenda as a inner join agendap as p on a.id_agenda = p.agenda_agendap where p.pessoa_agendap = $id_pessoa and data_agenda = '$ano-$mes-$inicio' or a.termino_agenda = '$ano-$mes-$inicio'");
                                $reg2 = $dados2->fetchObject();

                                if (!empty($reg2)) {
                                    $compromisso = '<small>';

                                    $d = connection::select("select * from agenda where (data_agenda <= '$ano-$mes-$inicio' AND termino_agenda >= '$ano-$mes-$inicio')");

                                    foreach ($d as $r) {
                                        $compromisso .= '#' . $r['id_agenda'] . ' - ' . $r['compromisso_agenda'] . '<br>';
                                    }
                                    $compromisso .= '</small>';

                                    $calendario .="<div style='background-color:#fff;' class='cabecalho_dia' value='$inicio/$mes/$ano'><a href=" . URL . "agenda/data/$ano-$mes-$inicio>" . $inicio . "<br><font style='color:#fff;background-color:#166C25;'>" . $compromisso . "</font></div>";
                                }
                                else {
                                    $calendario .="<div style='background-color:#fff;' class='cabecalho_dia' value='$inicio/$mes/$ano'><a href=" . URL . "agenda/data/$ano-$mes-$inicio>" . $inicio . "</a></div>";
                                }

                                if ($inicio == $ultimo_dia_mes) {
                                    $fim = "T";
                                }
                                $inicio++;
                            }
                            else {
                                $calendario .="<div style='background-color:#fff;' class='cabecalho_dia'>&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>";
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    $html = str_replace('#CALENDARIO#', $calendario, $html);
```

Comment: Eduardo2222, ainda precisa de ajuda?